# c# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : for chromedriver.exe (nuget pkg version 2.46.0)

Tags: c#, .net-core, selenium-chromedriver

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException :

> A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to
>   the remote WebDriver server for URL
>   http://localhost:49730/session/c097260d15be5935b9842a216fa2903d/element.

The status of the exception was UnknownError, and the message was:

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
>   is normally permitted

I am getting above error while executing scripts in parallel in `xunit`.
FYI - I have `.net core 2.2 xunit` automation project and I am using `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver 2.46.0` nuget pkg version. I also have    `chrome Version 72.0.3626` on my automation machine.

Can someone please assist me? Please let me know if you require more info.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by ensuring the tests being run were not making unnecessary looping calls to the WebDriver.

Every call to the WebDriver such as FindElements() seems to open a port. The loops which were placed into our code were spamming the WebDriver and causing Windows to experience Thread Exhaustion.

So long as the tests ran sequentially the error was not experienced, they only appeared during parallel execution.